# Typo3 - How to add dynamic value in TCA MM table

Tags: typo3

I'm trying to add a column to the relation table (MM table) in Typo3. Let's say I have my tables `user`, `wanted_car` and `wanted_car_mm` which is my relation table. So in `wanted_car_mm` I'll know what user want which car, but I want to add the column `need_faster` in `wanted_car_mm`, which is a boolean, that tells me who should have it faster. A lot of users could need it faster, there's no order.

**How do I add this column, map the value and correctly retrieve this information when I get all my users?**

I currently have this in my TCA config for `user`:

```
'wanted_cars' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:caa_my_plugin/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:my_title',
    'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => 'wanted_car',
        'MM' => 'wanted_car_mm',
        'MM_insert_fields' => array('need_faster' => '???'),
        'MM_table_where' => ' AND wanted_car_mm.need_faster = ???',
        'maxitems' => 9999,
        'multiple' => 0,
        'renderType' => 'selectCheckBox',
    ),
),
```

I feel like this is how I should add the column and retrieve it correctly, but I have no clue how to map the correct value.. that I should also put in my where clause.. I don't know how this can be possible going like this, but I can't find any other way of doing it.

The value must be specified when creating a `user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an intermediate table for that. The full docs for that can be found on https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html

a screenshot and old example which still should work can also be found on https://wiki.typo3.org/Inline_Relational_Record_Editing_Attributes

Comment: So basically I should remove the MM table and change my `'type' => 'select'` for `'type' => 'inline'`. I'll see what can be done, but since most of the code was already built with the MM table in mind, I'm not sure it can be a solution.. but I'm giving it a try

Comment: Actually I'll see if I could keep that MM table but add another one only for the `need_faster` attribute

Comment: I'll accept your answer since I feel like this should be the correct way of doing it, but I ended up removing the `MM_insert_fields` and `MM_table_where` from my TCA config and added a column to the table in `ext_tables.sql`. I created a repository in which I added 2 methods.. one for updating the MM column and another one to retrieve it. Since I create those objects programmatically it's not much of a problem.